# Guides on how to set up Xcode projects for big teams?

Tags: xcode

We're 5 people who want to start developing a big project. It's an in-house enterprise iPad app only specifically for our company and nobody else.

We know how to develop apps with normal Xcode projects but have never used SVN or anything like that before. Bad think I know. But now we want to do it the right way.

Are there guidelines, tutorials, articles or videos that explain how development in big teams works with Xcode? I guess we would need to set up some sort of repository on some sort of server and then everyone would have to check out/in the project files. But no idea how?!

Any resource that helps would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call a 5 person team a 'Big team' :)

Comment: That's in the view of any individual, I guess. For me, 5 are a LOT. I live in a country where iOS devs are rare. Not the US :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust me. You dont want to have to go through the pains of SVN. I would suggest Mercurial, with [MacHG](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/) as a client. here is a good intro:

http://hginit.com/

If you want an easy way to get a repo up and running, and you dont have a server to host it, try going here: http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/ and use the free trial till you can get something more stable up and running.

Answer (score 2):

Our team uses Mercurial for our source control. It's a distributed system of source control that doesn't necessarily tie you to a server.  Everyone has a copy of the repository.  We use it for our iOS projects and have been very happy with it.

Comment: Are there articles that explain how to integrate Mercurial in Xcode and how to set things up quickly?

Comment: @BugAlert look at my answer, unfortunately, mercurial and xcode dont integrate, but MacHG is very simple to use, and has a great interface

Comment: What are the drawbacks because of the non-integration with Xcode? Is it hard to use on a daily basis?

Comment: Heres the quick start guide http://mercurial.selenic.com/quickstart/. We just installed it on our local machines and a home computer as a "server". We weren't ready to post our code offsite so chose this model.  We also use Murky2 to view file differences.

Comment: Not really, I use it every day, I just pin it to my dock next to xcode, and when I am complete with a revision in xcode, i open mac HG, select all files in the local repository, and click "add remove files" then commit with a message, and viola, I have committed `Locally`. If I have something that I know works perfectly, then I `Push` it to the server... Note for usernames/passwords for server: It uses bash, so it is recommended that passwords are alphanumeric for MacHG, I had that problem...

Comment: Interesting! How would I set up that server? Gonna read those links now.

Answer (score 2):

git is definitely worth checking out (imo). it is documented and free (it will also be integrated with XC4). it will probably take some time to get to grips with distributed vcs at first - but it's a very nice program (generally much faster than svn too). on osx, there are also several options for clients.

as far as where to host the project: in the office, with remote access (+some offsite backup scheme).

Comment: I only know github. They want money for commercial projects, and the stuff is online on a server. Can we use git without github?

Comment: yes -- just use a machine at the office which you all have network access to. fwiw, i can't comment on the stability/usability of XC4's git integration - but git does work well using other clients (or the command line, if you prefer).